# Are these sound libraries system-required?

Tags: apt, sound, 19.10, mycroft

I'm trying to install Mycroft AI and it tells me it has conflicting packages it will have to remove. These are:

libasound2-plugins:i386 libjack-jackd2-0 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 mplayer

These look like sound and video libraries

I know for a fact mplayer isn't important since I installed it myself, but what about the others?

Comment: I think they are important